# Get incremental data from SurveyMonkey Apply Rest API

Tags: rest, etl, surveymonkey

For analytical purposes, I wish to extract incremental data from SurveyMonkey Apply using its Rest APIs. Some of the endpoints that I am going to use are Activity, Users, Programs and Applications.
This is the SMA documentation that I am referring to.

https://connect.smapply.io/pages/resources.html#activity

To enable incremental load, I need a timestamp field such as "updated_at". It seems SMA has this field in the endpoint schemas but **updated_at **is not a part of Query Parameters.

There is a way to create filters and pass in the query parameters. How can I apply this filter in the APIs?

[Query parameters for SurveyMonkey Apply Activity API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q15A0.png)

If I pass a single timestamp value to an activity API, it returns a record. However, I wish to provide a date range. How can I pass the range as query parameter SMA APIs?

[create_at works with a single value with equal operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaDJQ.png)

SMA documentation is not clear. What can I try next?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.